# Create a Base Class via Java Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I want to use an annotation processor to generate the base class of the class being annotated.  Something like this:

```
@ClassGenerator(name="FakeClass") // Generates FakeClass
public class MyClass extends FakeClass {
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?  Or should I look at other patterns.

Comment: @Fildor It would make the class I have to build more elegant.  I need to be able to override stuff in the generated class.  My alternative would be to split it up: 1 class that defines what needs to be generated, a second class that derives from that class that has all of the overrides.

Comment: @afzalex Can a Processor-generated class replace an existing class definition?  I was under the impression that it could not.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your question. Can you make it more clear.

Comment: Is that better?  I'm trying to generate the class's own super class.  In particular see the code snippet's comment.

Comment: But why would you need the superclass? You couldn't possibly use it elsewhere?

Comment: Because I want to override some of the generated class functionality by hand, particularly constructors but also have some additional methods.  If I could generate a bunch of stuff in the annotated class, that'd be ideal, but as far as I'm aware that's not possible without bytecode hackery, and that wouldn't be approved.  If this was C# I'd make it a partial class and generate the other half, but there's not a way to do this in my build environment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly... Sure, you just need to scan for `ClassGenerator` and generate the missing class.  Here's a basic working processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("ClassGenerator")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class BaseClassProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Elements elements;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        elements = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ClassGenerator.class)) {
            TypeMirror mirror = ((TypeElement) element).getSuperclass();

            PackageElement pacakgeElement = elements.getPackageOf(element);
            String packageName = pacakgeElement.getQualifiedName().toString();
            String superClassName = ((DeclaredType) mirror).asElement().getSimpleName().toString();

            try {
                Writer file = processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile(packageName + "." + superClassName).openWriter();
                file.write(String.format("package %s; public class %s {}", packageName, superClassName));
                file.flush();
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BaseClassProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As for whether this pattern is advisable or best, you'd have to analyze your requirements and determine if this satisfies your needs.